# Vim :set mouse=a works in ubuntu but not fedora

Tags: fedora, vim, mouse, clipboard

I want to be able to highlight text without it selecting the numbers for the lines or spilling into another split I have open. The `mouse=a` option does that perfectly on Ubuntu, but when I switch over to a Fedora system it won't let me copy with the same keyboard shortcut that worked on the Ubuntu system in the same terminal emulator. It will highlight like it should but won't copy.

I tried `mouse=r` and `v` and also holding shift while highlighting. None of them worked, and I don't really consider shift a solution since I want consistent results across both systems. I think it has to do with Fedora's default `vimrc` in `/etc`, but I don't know enough to start deleting lines in there.

Comment: According to your description, `:set mouse=a` do work on both systems. You say that the copying does not work on Fedora, while in Ubuntu it did with a keyboard shortcut. What keyboard shortcut is that and how do you attempt the paste? There you will find the issue. Also, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584242) will probably prove helpful (it's my answer, sorry for the self-reference but I really think it will be helpful).

Comment: Can you post the values of `set clipboard?` and `set guioptions?` on both systems?

Comment: Are you using a vim binary with support for `+clipboard` on Fedora? Check what `vim --version` says about it... You might need to use a `vimx` binary to get proper clipboard support.